# AES decryption not working in nodeJS/ExpressJS backend

Tags: javascript, express, next.js, aes

I am trying to decrypt data after it is received from mongoDb. The data received from db, some part of it is in encrypted the rest is not.

```js
app.get("/recieve", async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const data = await UploadData.find();

        const decryptedData = data.map((item) => {
            const decryptedFullName = decryptData(item.fullname, secretKey);
            const decryptedCatName = decryptData(item.catName, secretKey);
            const decryptedEmail = decryptData(item.email, secretKey);
            const decryptedContact = decryptData(item.contact, secretKey);
            const decryptedLocation = decryptData(item.location, secretKey);

            return {
                ...item.toObject(),
                fullname: decryptedFullName,
                catName: decryptedCatName,
                email: decryptedEmail,
                contact: decryptedContact,
                location: decryptedLocation,
            };
        });
        res.json(decryptedData);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error fetching data:", error);
        res.status(500).json({ error: "Internal server error" });
    }
});
```

here is the **UPDATED** decryption function:

```js
function decryptData(encryptedData, key) {
    try {
        const buff = Buffer.from(encryptedData, "base64");
        encryptedData = buff.toString("utf-8");
        var decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv("aes-256-cbc", key, iv);
        return (
            decipher.update(encryptedData, "base64", "utf8") +
            decipher.final("utf8")
        );
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("Error decrypting data:", error);
        return null;
    }
}
```

If you want to see how i **UPDATED** encrypted my data here is the code for function:

```js
function encryptData(data, key) {
    console.log("Encrypted called");

    const keyBuffer = Buffer.from(key, "hex");
    const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv("aes-256-cbc", keyBuffer, iv);

    let encryptedData =
        cipher.update(data, "utf8", "base64") + cipher.final("base64");
    return Buffer.from(encryptedData).toString("base64");
}
```

This is how i am creating the iv and key.

```js
const crypto = require("crypto");

const secretKey = crypto.randomBytes(32);
const iv = crypto.randomBytes(8).toString("hex");
```

with the latest updates im recieving the error bad decrypt

Comment: In your code, the IVs seem to be different for encryption and decryption. The correct way is to store the random IV generated during encryption so that it is available for decryption (since the IV is not secret, it is usually concatenated with the ciphertext and can then be separated during decryption based on the known IV length).

Comment: I have tried that as well im going to update the code.

Comment: Not reproducible, s. https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/NFT. Post non-productive sample data: key, IV, plaintext, and ciphertext. Please format the code as well.

Comment: Btw regarding the IV: apply the IV as *raw 16* bytes and not *hex encoded 8* bytes.

Comment: wait IT WORKED THANK YOUUUUU

Comment: you can write it as an answer so i will upvote it and accept it

Comment: You are welcome. I'll make it an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For decryption, the same IV must be used as for encryption. This is not the case with the code you (originally) posted, which is the cause of the problem.

Usually, a random IV is generated for each encryption (so that multiple encryptions with the same key do not result in the reuse of key/IV pairs, which would be a vulnerability). The generated IV is concatenated with the ciphertext and passed to the decrypting side in this way. Since the IV is not a secret, its disclosure does not pose a security problem.
During decryption, the IV and ciphertext are separated based on the known IV length.

A sample implementation with the *crypto* module of NodeJS is:

```js
const crypto = require("crypto");

function encryptData(plaintext, key) {
    const iv = crypto.randomBytes(16);                                                                  // generate a random IV for each encryption
    const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv("aes-256-cbc", key, iv);
    return Buffer.concat([iv, cipher.update(plaintext, "utf8"), cipher.final()]).toString("base64");    // encrypt, concatenate IV and ciphertext
}
                
function decryptData(ciphertextB64, key) {
    const ivCiphertext = Buffer.from(ciphertextB64, "base64");                                  
    const iv = ivCiphertext.subarray(0, 16);                                                            // separate IV...
    const ciphertext = ivCiphertext.subarray(16);                                                       // ...and ciphertext
    const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv("aes-256-cbc", key, iv);
    return Buffer.concat([decipher.update(ciphertext), decipher.final()]).toString("utf8");             // decrypt
}
                
const key = crypto.randomBytes(32); // apply a random byte sequence as key
const encryptedData = encryptData("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog", key);
const decryptedData = decryptData(encryptedData, key);
console.log(decryptedData); // The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
```